# how does fsync system call work in linux?

Tags: linux

When write call returns, the data is copied onto some page managed by kernel. That page can contain writes from multiple process. So, when one of the applications issues fsync call, will this result in flushing the whole page, which means flushing other applications data also, but the cost would be incurred by the process which calls fsync. Is this correct?

Answer (score 9):

`fsync` operates on a single file. It will flush *all* changes made to that file. If multiple processes are writing into a single file the process that made the `fsync` call will be paused until *all* the changes are written to disk.

This is more complicated when some journaling filesystems come into play. For example, ext3 and ext4 (to a lesser extent) with the "ordered" mode are required to flush all the changes to *all* of the files ahead of the fsync file in the journal.

That means that if programs have been writing to a large database or a large log file or a video file and you then `fsync` a two-line configuration file, your `fsync` must wait for all those megabytes of data to be written before it can return.

This is why I run my ext4 in "writeback" mode, which can have some unpleasant consequences after a crash such as files of the correct size but filled with zeroes. But in normal operation "writeback" is so much faster that I feel the tradeoff is worth it.

Comment: Imagine a virtual memory page, which contains writes from application A and B. If application A calls fsync, will the kernel only sync the page selectively? Also is the default mode for ext4 "ordered"?

Comment: @Jimm: In the disk cache files never share memory pages so this will not happen.

Comment: @Jimm Pages in the OS memory cache that belong to a file are either marked dirty(which mean the page has changed) or they're not dirty(hasn't changed). When A calls fsync on that file, all the dirty pages belonging to that file are written to the drive, regardless of which process has changed it.

Comment: @nos my understanding is that there is no concept of memory pages maintained per file. imagine, that you create a file and write one line. Os will not initilize a memory pages specially for that write, because once user has issued a write, irrespective of whichfile it belongs to, the file system driver enqueues it to be delivered to the disk driver.two writes from 2 seperate process can end up on the same memory page.

Comment: @ZanLynx how can you be sure? ext4 shares memory pages and ext4 enqueues the data to disk driver.

Comment: @Jimm There's a caching layer in there that takes care of this. There really will be memory allocated to the data of that write, unless it's overwriting existing parts of the file, in which case an existing page that mirrors the data on the drive will be used(which might need to be loaded first). write() calls are not synchronous calls, it's just writing to memory, and the OS will flush that data to the drive asyncronously.

Answer (score 2):

The man page states `'flushes to disk any data written to this file'`  which includes file metadata.

I think you are confusing this with `sync`  which does write all the dirty pages from the entire cache to disk.  Dirty page == changed data.  And the process has to wait for all of that to complete.  If by cost you mean wait, then yes this one incurs cost.  Kernel time is added to the process system time  resource usage.

fsync also incurs cost, plus a much smaller amount of kernel time than sync(usually).